# In Vue.js, how can I get a keypress event to get the latest version of the input?

Tags: vue.js

In the following code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WYJopq

I monitor key presses and try to clone the input into another input as follows:

```
  [![methods: {
    clone: function() {
      this.mirror = this.original;
    }
  }]
```

But the cloned input is always one keystroke behind:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2uCA.gif

How do I update my code so that the cloned input exactly matches the original input?

(Note: I know for this simple example, there's an idiomatic Vue.js way to do things, but I'm specifically interested in doing this via keystroke monitoring)

Comment: Have you tried using `keyup` instead of `keypress`?

Comment: is there a reason you are using keypress instead of keyup?

Answer (score 4):

With a keyboard, we have three events fired in the following order:

1. `keydown` - fired before character inserted
2. `keypress` - fired when a character is getting inserted
3. `keyup` - fired when character is already inserted

In this scenario, if you need input with updated characters, you should use `keyup` event which is after the character is inserted into the input.

Having said this, you should probably use `@input` event as relying on the keyboard means you are not thinking about other ways via which text can be inserted into the input box. For example, copy-paste or using an on-screen keyboard:

```
<input type="text" v-model="original" @input="clone()" />
```